# странное поведение elem.scrollHeight'а

Tags: javascript, dom, прокрутка, style, padding

Есть такой стиль:

```
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
margin: 25px;
padding: 20px;
border: 25px solid #777;
overflow: auto;
```

Элемент: `<div id="test">lorem100</div>`

```
var test = document.getElementById("test");

console.log(test.scrollHeight);  // 400

test.style.height = test.scrollHeight + "px";

console.log(test.scrollHeight);  // 440
```

Ну и вопрос: откуда берутся ещё 40 пикселей, после того как мы разворачиваем элемент на всю высоту?

Тут как-то замешан padding. Потому что если его убрать - будет 360 и 360. То есть какого-то лешего padding добавляется дважды. Кто знает - почему и зачем?

Comment: padding добавляется со всех 4 сторон, поэтому высота + padding*2

Comment: @1px_solid_black всё вам Artem правильно подсказал, вам нужно было своей головой маленько подумать. :\

Answer (score 2):

Согласно спецификации CSS ширина блока складывается из ширины контента (width), значений отступов (margin), полей (padding) и границ (border). Аналогично обстоит и с высотой блока.

Если хотите изменить алгоритм расчёта, используйте св-во [`box-sizing`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing)

### Синтаксис

`box-sizing: content-box | border-box | padding-box | inherit`

### Значения

- `content-box` - Основывается на стандартах CSS, при этом свойства width и height задают ширину и высоту контента и не включают в себя значения отступов, полей и границ.
- `border-box` - Свойства width и height включают в себя значения полей и границ, но не отступов (margin). Эта модель используется браузером Internet Exporer в режиме несовместимости.
- `padding-box` - 
  Свойства width и height включают в себя значения полей, но не отступов (margin) и границ (border).

**UPD**

`scrollHeight` - полная внутренняя высота, включая прокрученную область

Изначально у вас есть некая высота `height` допустим 200 и `padding` равный 20. 
При выводе `console.log(test.scrollHeight);` вы получаете `высота + (padding * 2)` т.е. 240  
 
После того как вы присвоили элементу новую высоту, уже суммированную автоматически браузером, т.е. 240 вы получаете на вывод через log новую суммированную высоту, т.е. `240 + padding * 2` = 280

Comment: ты к чему это написал? Ты вопрос мой читал? К чему мне твой box-sizing? У меня нету проблем с вёрсткой! Вопрос вообще о другом! Спрашиваю у тебя почему 360px + два паддинга (ВВЕРХУ И СНИЗУ) по 20px = 440px ? Ферштейн?

Comment: @1px_solid_black обновил ответ. И не зачем хамить людям, которые пытаются вам помочь. Вы нарушаете правило "будьте доброжелательны". Люди на вас своё время личное тратят.

Comment: @1px_solid_black https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice